# Counter Strike Global Offensive runs a little slow

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

I installed Counter-Strike Global Offensive on my MacBook. It works but sometimes it's running a little bit slow (freezing, lagging).

The specs on my computer:

- 2.4 GHz Intel Core 2 Duo
- 4GB RAM
- NVIDIA GeForce 9400M 256 MB

I turned all the video settings I could find in the game menu to the lowest option possible.

Is there anything else I can do to make the game run smoother? Maybe change some advanced setting from the console?

Comment: 9400M is very weak. I already have a performance issues with my more advanced 9600M GT

Comment: net_graph 3 in console (during gameplay) and see what your stats look like. FPS, choke, and loss are the three numbers you want to be looking at to try to identify the problem more specifically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of csgo, there are no real configs that could really affect your fps, aside from those in the video settings, so those are the only ones that you can tweak around and test with.

Even the developers said a hardware upgrade is probably the best solution to a low fps problem.

I would say it is purely your graphix card's limit, instead of the game settings.

Hope that helped.

Comment: Thanks, Nick. That makes sense. What surprises me though is that a friend of mine is able to run CS GO smoothly on a slightly newer MacBook but with the same graphic card as mine.

Comment: In some rare cases, a cpu difference/ram could cause fps difference, and as time passes you might have more junk files or such in your operating system that could also affect your performance, but these are minor issues. 

Lets say one computer is slightly older than another, having 90% of the stuff same as another computer, but having a gfx card that is a lot better, this computer, even older, will perform better in games.